# Running Eclipse-CDT on Ubuntu 18.04 causes java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-cdt

I am running a Virtual Machine of Ubuntu 18.04 via Oracle VirtualBox. 
I need Eclipse (including cdt) for a c++ project. So I ran the following statement on the console:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse eclipse-cdt g++
```

Then I waited until it finished installing. Afterwards, I tried to run Eclipse, which caused the following error:

> An error has occurred.  See the log file
>   /home/matthias/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1540208856928.log

So, I checked the log file. It says the following:

> !SESSION Mon Oct 22 13:38:43 CEST 2018
>   ----------------------------------------- !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2018-10-22 13:38:43.262 !MESSAGE
>   Exception launching the Eclipse Platform: !STACK
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter   at
>   java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)    at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

Unfortunately, I am an absolute beginner with Ubuntu, as well as c++. I have no idea what could cause this problem. Can anybody help me?

Comment: I'd recommend to just download the latest release of eclipse cdt directly from the website [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2018-09/r/eclipse-ide-cc-developers).

Comment: Many installation guides are recommending the manual download/install method.  Also rising in popularity is using snap with: `snap install eclipse`

Answer (score 1):

I found that on Ubuntu18.04 this is due to a [packaging problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eclipse/+bug/1754886) (debugged with the help of a talented coworker). The fix was to *manually install files from the older libequinox-osgi-java_3.8.1-8* package, to keep packaging happy.

1. Locate and get the .deb file
2. Examine contents of package vs. the system for overlaps
3. Manually extract deb into '/'

**Commands:**

```
$ cd /tmp
$ wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/e/eclipse/libequinox-osgi-java_3.8.1-8_all.deb

$ dpkg -c /tmp/libequinox-osgi-java_3.8.1-8_all.deb
$ dpkg -L libequinox-osgi-java

$ cd /
$ sudo dpkg -x /tmp/libequinox-osgi-java_3.8.1-8_all.deb
```

**Notes:**

Here we see commands to show eclipse depends on eclipse-rcp, which depends on libequinox-osgi-java (>= 3.9.1), which are all installed:

```
$ lsb_release -rc
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

$ apt-rdepends eclipse 2>&1 | egrep '^eclipse-rcp|libequinox-osgi-java'
eclipse-rcp
  Depends: libequinox-osgi-java (>= 3.9.1)
libequinox-osgi-java

$ dpkg-query -W eclipse eclipse-rcp libequinox-osgi-java
eclipse 3.8.1-11
eclipse-rcp     3.8.1-11
libequinox-osgi-java    3.9.1-1
```

These commands show that the out-of-the box eclipse stubbornly insists on loading the older osgi_3.8.1.dist.jar despite not being able to stat it or open it:

```
$ strace -f -e trace=file /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse -debug -clean -initialize 2>&1 |
    egrep '^Framework.located|file:.*osgi_3.*jar|stat.*osgi_3.*jar'
[pid 117096] stat("/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.dist.jar", 0x7f4f0ca95540) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 117096] stat("/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.dist.jar", 0x7f4f0ca954c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 117096] stat("/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.dist.jar", 0x7f4f0ca95550) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 117096] stat("/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.dist.jar", 0x7f4f0ca954d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
Framework located:
    file:/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.dist.jar
...
```

The older package just happens to be the same package used in the Ubuntu16.04 eclipse packages.  We tried a few different ways to force install both older and newer packages, etc. but this made packaging unhappy and the manual extract Just Worked(tm).